# Make ImageView large when tapped - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I am learning android and want to implement the following scenario and I hope I'll get a good advice to get started.

In the following screen, there are some clickable buttons that represent the sports

[FindSports][1]

and when the user taps on any one of the icon/image it should become a little bit big from other so it stands out from other icons ( it should look like this image)

[Choosen Sport][2]

Any help is much appreciated :)

PS: sorry for my bad English and if it is already answered.

Answer (score 0):

All views have a [`setScaleX()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScaleX(float)) and [`setScaleY()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScaleY(float)) method that you can use to change the size of the view. You probably want to call those methods in an `onClickListener`